# Plotting variables of multiple agents

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to plot a graph that shows the variables of all agents of one breed. Although the number of agents is rather small, I think there must be a more elegant way than creating a pen for every agent. Is there?

Answer (score 4):

Elegance, here, depends on what exactly you want to do. It can be perfectly legitimate to create one plot pen per turtle, using [`create-temporary-plot-pen`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#create-temporary-plot-pen). Among advantages, it means that you can give each plot pen a name and show a legend on your plot.

That being said, it's also very easy to use a single pen for all your agents. Suppose you have multiple turtles, of different colors, and you want to plot their sizes. You can put something like this in a pen's "update commands":

```
ask turtles [ set-plot-pen-color color plotxy ticks size ]
```

This will change the pen to the color of each turtle and plot a single point for that turtle. Just be sure to set your pen to "point" mode in the advanced pen options.

Also notice the use of [`plotxy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plotxy) instead of just [`plot`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plot), allowing you to specify an *x* coordinate instead of relying on the "auto advance" behavior of `plot`.